# How to make an if statement using value from case

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I have a `select` statement and the result is :

```
ax | country    | country_id | town   | pop |
1  | neverland  | 1          | ntown  | 10  |
1  | wonderland | 2          | wtown  | 20  |
2  | wonderland | 2          | wLtown | 20  |
1  | toysIsland | 3          | ttown  | 5   |
```

but it supposed to be like:

```
ax | country    | country_id | town   | pop |
1  | neverland  | 1          | ntown  | 10  |
1  | wonderland | 2          | wtown  | 20  |
2  | wonderland | 2          | wLtown | NULL|
1  | toysIsland | 3          | ttown  | 5   |
```

I have an `if` statement using value from `case` :

```
select (case country
when @c
then @co = @co +1
else @co = 1, @c = country
end ) as ax,
country, country_id, town, (case when town_id = param_ti then population_c) as pop
from tb_town a left join
tb_country b on b.country_id = a.country_id;

if ax = 1 then
 pop= pop
else
 pop= '';
end if;
```

I don't know what I should write in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change to your query

```
select (case country when @c then @co = @co +1
        else @co = 1, @c = country
        end ) as ax,
        country, country_id, town, IF(town_id = param_ti, population_c, NULL) as pop
    from tb_town a left join
         tb_country b on b.country_id = a.country_id;
```

Comment: thank you so much, but i dont know, but the result just have 1 row :
     `1  | neverland  | 1          | ntown  | 10  |`
what should i do now?